# Angular: DOM manipulation and $compile not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have un little problem with DOM manipulation.

Here's my angular function:

```
$scope.modif = function (e) {
        $scope.temp = e.target.offsetParent.offsetParent.childNodes[3].childNodes[(this.$index+1)*2];
        $scope.temp.childNodes[11].innerHTML = $compile('<button ng-click="save($event)">Save</button>')($scope);
};
```

but my button is rendered like that in the document:

> [[object HTMLButtonElement]

I know that using innerHTML with Angular is wrong but when i'm using .html() i have this error:

```
$scope.modif = function (e) {
        $scope.temp = e.target.offsetParent.offsetParent.childNodes[3].childNodes[(this.$index+1)*2];
        $scope.temp.childNodes[11].html($compile('<button ng-click="save($event)">Save</button>')($scope));
};
```

> TypeError: undefined is not a function at h.$scope.modif

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

.html is a jQuery function, but childNodes is an array of DOM elements. Something like this should work:

```
$($scope.temp.childNodes[11]).html($compile('<button ng-click="save($event)">Save</button>')($scope));
```